# How to make popup like keyboard characters in iOS8 custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I want to create popup in iOS8 custom keyboard as shown below image.

[image: Want to create this type of keyboard in iOS8]

Some code are working but can't access outer window of keyboard and occures issue as shown in below image-2

[image: Issue in iOS8 Custom Keyboard]

Answer (score 6):

This what i have done in my custom Keyboard its working

```
//adding pop up when character is tapped
- (void)addPopupToButton:(UIButton *)button
{


    CGRect frame,frame1;
    if(self.view.frame.size.width == 320)
    {
        //Keyboard is in Portrait
        frame = CGRectMake(0, -25, 28, 43);
        frame1=CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 43);

    }
    else{
        //Keyboard is in Landscape
        frame = CGRectMake(3, -25, 35, 43);
        frame1=CGRectMake(0, 10, 35, 43);

    }
   //create pop up view
    UIView *popUp=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    //create a label to add to pop up view
    UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    //set frame for the label and set label title
    [text setFrame:frame1];
    [text setText:button.titleLabel.text];
    text.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [text setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30]];
    text.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    //add label as popup view's subview
    [popUp addSubview:text];

    //add pop up view as button's subview
    [button addSubview:popUp];

}


//remove Pop up view
-(void)endPopUpForButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    if ([button subviews].count > 1)
    {
        [[[button subviews] objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, codeIgnitor can we add popup outside 320*216 frame? As I want to make bigger popup which goes outside this frame and the issue is that outer part of view is cropped down as shown in above image.

Comment: @ScorpianAlive, I had a same problem! for now i have set it to 320.0 for time being.. Will be working for a bigger popup.

Comment: @codeIgniter, I was asking can I make keyboard height bigger than 216?

Comment: @ScorpianAlive, Its possible to change the height of  your custom  keyboard by adding the NSLayoutconstraint to the view refer the code in this document https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html but not working in xcode beta 3 and 4

Comment: @codeIgnitor Thanks, Your link worked for custom height But, How to handle height changes for portrait- landscape orientations? As there remained same height on landscape, I tried to applied same code to reduce height but unable to handle orientation changes for keyboard height.

Comment: @VijayHirpara, You mean u tried the code inside the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method what was the result???

Answer (score 4):

From the [Apple App Extension Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html):

> Finally, it is not possible to display key artwork above the top edge
>   of a custom keyboard’s primary view, as the system keyboard does on
>   iPhone when you tap and hold a key in the top row.

So it seems like you can't add pop-up outside the keyboard frame, so codelgnitor's answer is the best you can do.

Comment: Can we do any custom code to achieve same functioanlity. As I found code for popup to show for single character, it works fine  but I need to show multiple characters , too for some keys.

Comment: You can put a hidden keyboard keys row on your keyboard, then make it visible when user do a long press gesture on a key.
Then hide it again when user press any key on that keyboard row.