# How to show an extra character on keyboard long press

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard

How can I add an extra character when long pressing a key on the virtual keyboard like in the following image:

[image: add extra character on long press event like long press "n" button on keyboard]

I am using [this library](https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards).

Comment: You have to create a custom keyboard since the standard keyboards cannot be changed.

Comment: if you know any library same like image link please suggest me  "http://i.stack.imgur.com/0mJQ2.png"

Comment: The library you are using does not support long pressing keyboard keys

Comment: custom keyboard with additional gesture will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a well-explained programming guide for custom keyboards [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html).

According to that guide:

> These features and others are listed next.
>
> - Appropriate layout and features based on keyboard type trait
> - Autocorrection and suggestion
> - Automatic capitalization
> - Automatic period upon double space
> - Caps lock support
> - Keycap artwork
> - Multistage input for ideographic languages
>
> You can decide whether or not to implement such features; there is no
>   dedicated API for any of the features just listed, so providing them
>   is a competitive advantage.

Your keyword here is `Keycap Artwork`.

So, like they said, there is no dedicated api for this. You can design this with known, regular ways. Like, adding a `tap gesture recognizer` to letter buttons, and displaying some view includes extra characters to top-right edge of letter button when letter is long pressed.

Or alternatively, you can create a second keyboard contains your custom chars and let users switch between default keyboard and your one.

**Update:**

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377846/how-to-make-popup-like-keyboard-characters-in-ios8-custom-keyboard) question. Those answers may help you to decide what to do.

Comment: cyrkeyboardbutton library not working for me because i have already list of UIButton. open popup on UIButton long press event.

Comment: @user3091160 did you consider adding a second keyboard and let users switch between them?

Comment: cyrkeyboardbutton not working with touchesMoved event.